# Only telecommute jobs check box not working

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

I'm looking for telecommute jobs but when doing a search using the Only Telecommute Jobs checkbox, jobs offering relocation are showing up instead.

Comment: Could be from listings trying to make you think they're amenable to remote work, but only if remote means when you've clocked out for the day while onsite for the rest

Comment: Can you point me at a specific job that's showing up in the results that shouldn't be? Everything I'm seeing right now is either solely telecommute or it's telecommute and they're offering relocation as well. I'm not seeing anything that's not telecommute.

Comment: @JasonPunyon How can you tell if it's telecommute? For instance, [this](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/23274/a-letter-to-hard-working-but-currently-amazon-in-orange-county?a=ruSepa0) doesn't say anything about tele. If I do a keyword search and click "telecommute" I get 1059 jobs. If I click "view all" I get 1059 jobs. If I put in a distance and no keywords I get 1059 jobs. Contrast with a day or two ago when it seemed to work for me. The terms are in the URL, but I don't think they're sticking.

Comment: @DaveNewton: Hmm. I see it now.

Comment: @JasonPunyon, Not sure if this is related, but I noticed something funky with the `GET` request.  Under Chrome developer tools, it only sends `ajax=1` even though the querystring in the URL appears to change.  If I copy and paste the URL and do a "manual" `GET` through the browser (chrome, win7), it works.

Comment: @hyperslug: Yep related.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks for the report. Someone got a little overzealous refactoring some javascript. Everything should be back to normal now.

Comment: Just in the nick of time!